# best way for a multiplayer lobby in a smartphone game

Tags: mobile, login, registration, games

This is how it works now: At this time it is a web app and then:

1. users choose an ID and a password,
2. then create a new game,
3. the server returns the code of the new game created,
4. the other players join the game corresponding to that code.

I don't know the logic I should use in a smartphone:

it seems rude to ask the user an ID and a password, and it seems stupid to me to have such a complex way to manage the hosting/joining mechanism: it would be much simpler if the user could just search the friends to invite in his phone-contact-list.

However, what is the most convenient way to implement a multiplayer game in a smartphone, particularly concerning the logging-in, the search of friends, the hosting and the joining?

I mean, what do average users usually expect in a multiplayer app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the order for a car racing iPhone game such as Need For Speed.

1. each person must register with Origin (EA's online multiplayer gaming platform) in order to play multiplayer.
2. Origin allows you to, like you said, search through iPhone Contacts and add friends.
3. After friend accepts your request you may invite him/her to new
   game.